# How can I connect to an Oracle Autonomous Data Warehouse with a 3rd party IDE (DataGrip)?

Tags: oracle, tnsnames, datagrip, wallet

I'm trying to connect to a Oracle Autonomous Data Warehouse database with Jetbrains DataGrip. Oracle provides me with a wallet file (a zip), with contains tnsnames.ora, a keystore, ojdbc.properties, and some other files.

I'm having a lot of trouble using this information to connect to the database using DataGrip. I found a thread on the DataGrip support forums, but I'm not having any luck with that either.

Jetbrains support thread: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001792539-Connect-with-Oracle-Cloud
Relevant Oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/adwud/connect-using-client-application.html

**What I did:**
1. Created the 'TNS_ADMIN' environment variable and set it to:
`C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\[folder with wallet files]`
2. Added the Oracle JDBC driver files (ojdbc8.jar, osdt_cert.jar, oraclepki.jar, osdt_core.jar) to the standard Oracle driver in DataGrip
3. edited the 'sqlnet.ora' file to include the path to the wallet files
4. Added the following to the Data Source VM Options:

```
-Doracle.net.tns_admin=C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\[folder with wallet files]
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=[password]
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore.jks    
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=[password]
-Doracle.net.ssl_server_dn_match=true    
-Doracle.net.ssl_version=1.2
```

5. Set connection type to URL only
6. Tried different connection strings in the URL field:

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@//adb.eu-frankfurt-1.oraclecloud.com:1522/xxxxxx_adw1_high.adwc.oraclecloud.com?TNS_ADMIN=C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\[folder with wallet files]`

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxx_adw1_high.adwc.oraclecloud.com?TNS_ADMIN=C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\[folder with wallet files]`

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@//adb.eu-frankfurt-1.oraclecloud.com:1522/mnr6yzqr22jgywm_adw1_high.adwc.oraclecloud.com`

**Result:**

```
Connection to ADW1 failed.  
[08006][17002] IO Error: Got minus one from a read call, connect lapse 32 ms.,  
Authentication lapse 0 ms.
```

I have also tried using the 'Service name' and 'TNS' connection types and filled in the info from tnsnames.ora. No dice, same error.

Also tried explicitely setting the 'tcp.validnode_checking' parameter to null.

(The connection works fine with sqldeveloper)

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Have you tries fill paths to key/trus strore?

Comment: Good suggestion. Tried it (also with quotes around the path, and also without the backslashes escaped), to no avail...

Comment: Please try to go to Data Source VM Options and put there full path to key/trus store. 

Something like
`-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\full_path\truststore.jks`

Comment: @moscas That was the answer, thanks. To clarify the full settings for anyone having the same problem, here are the settings to use in the new datasource screen:

In 'VM Options' add these lines:
-Doracle.net.tns_admin=C:\\path\\to\\wallet
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\\path\\to\\wallet\\truststore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<wallet pw>
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\\path\\to\\wallet\\truststore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<wallet pw>
-Doracle.net.ssl_server_dn_match=true
-Doracle.net.ssl_version=1.2

In Options
-Check 'Introspect schema with JDBC metadata'

Comment: In 'General'
-Use TNS connection type
-Field 'TNSADMIN' -> Make sure the full path to tnsnames.ora is filled in
-Field 'TNS name' -> Everything after '=' in tnsnames.ora (including braces)
-Field 'User' -> Fill in schema username
-Field 'Password' -> Fill in schema password

Comment: This guide maybe help you https://medium.com/oracledevs/java-development-with-autonomous-transaction-processing-dedicated-atp-d-f0355a2f9abd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGrip 2021.1 provides Oracle 21.1 JDBC driver with all required jar files.

Read DataGrip help about [Oracle connection using wallets](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/connect-to-oracle-cloud-by-using-wallets.html).

There are some additional [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/connect-jdbc-thin-wallet.html#GUID-1640CC02-BF3E-48C2-8FFE-A596614A6A40) references.

Comment: More info: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-8477